# Inline apple script

Tags: applescript, osascript

I need to write the following script inline

```
tell app "Spotify Queue"
    addTrack "spotify:track:7sa1xOgT1c8xQfbSL5FrCe"
end tell
```

like this one

```
sh('osascript -e \'tell app "Spotify" to playpause\'')
```

but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multilines:

```
tell app "Spotify Queue" to addTrack "spotify:track:7sa1xOgT1c8xQfbSL5FrCe"
```

If you do require more than one line, osascript can be used like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder"' -e 'display dialog "Multi-line"' -e 'end'
```

Comment: So just a `sh('tell app "Spotify Queue" ...')` should do the trick then?

Comment: I don't know CoffeeScript but from his example above, it seems like it should work

Comment: The quoting is mostly like JavaScript so you can put double quoted things inside single quoted strings (and vice versa). The `-e` version would probably be best done with a [block string](http://coffeescript.org/#strings) to avoid the quote escaping nonsense, `"""..."""` is more or less like a heredoc in the shell.